# android path shifted once finger is removed

Tags: android, canvas, path, bitmap

I am working on a drawing app and allows users to import image to further draw on it. Images bigger than the drawing area will then be scaled down such that to meet the max screenwidth or screenheight.

The imported image would be placed at center of the drawingView using  `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x_adjustment, y_adjustment, paintScreen);`

In this way there would be blank spaces on left, right or top, down of the imported image. The adjustment would be counting from (0,0)

`x_adjustment` and `y_adjustment`

## Coding:

**onDraw**

```
   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)   
   {
       canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x_adjustment, y_adjustment, paintScreen); 

      for (Integer key : pathMap.keySet()) 
         canvas.drawPath(pathMap.get(key), paintLine); // draw line
   }
```

**touchStarted:**

```
   private void touchStarted(float x, float y, int lineID) 
   {      
      Path path; // used to store the path for the given touch id
      Point point; // used to store the last point in path

         path = new Path(); // create a new Path
         pathMap.put(lineID, path); // add the Path to Map
         point = new Point();
         previousPointMap.put(lineID, point);

      path.moveTo(x, y);
      point.x = (int) x;  
      point.y = (int) y;         
   }
```

**touchMoved:**

```
   // called when the user drags along the screen
   private void touchMoved(MotionEvent event) 
   {
      // for each of the pointers in the given MotionEvent
      for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) 
      {
         // get the pointer ID and pointer index
         int pointerID = event.getPointerId(i);
         int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(pointerID);

         if (pathMap.containsKey(pointerID)) 
         {
            // get the new coordinates for the pointer
            float newX = event.getX(pointerIndex);
            float newY = event.getY(pointerIndex);

            // get the Path and previous Point associated with this pointer
            Path path = pathMap.get(pointerID);
            Point point = previousPointMap.get(pointerID);

            float deltaX = Math.abs(newX - point.x);
            float deltaY = Math.abs(newY - point.y);

            if (deltaX >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || deltaY >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) 
            {
               path.quadTo(point.x, point.y, ((newX + point.x)/2),((newY + point.y)/2));

               // store the new coordinates
               point.x = (int) newX ;
               point.y = (int) newY ;                   
            }
         } 
      }          
   }
```

**touchEnded:**

```
   private void touchEnded(int lineID)
   {
      Path path = pathMap.get(lineID); 
      bitmapCanvas.drawPath(path, paintLine); 
      path.reset();               
   }
```

### Question:

Since the imported image is placed at center but not (0,0), for every line drawn, though when it is showing properly when it is drawing and screen-touching, when the user removes the finger, i.e. Touch ended, the finalized line would be shifted by x_adjustment and y_adjustment.

e.g. If the scaled image width < screenwidth, there are blank space on left and right, when drawing the line is showing **correctly**, yet when the finger is removed, the line will **wrongly** immediately shift to right by `x_adjustment`;

I know it is because of the adjustments that make the error. I know it is to save the path's coordinates by a x,y shift. But I dont know how to modify for the codes and I have tried to add adjustment to the paths but still fails. Could anybody be kindly help to give me some guides? Many thanks!

Comment: I I do not see a reason for the `path` to be shifted, you might try to switch the order in your `onDraw` by drawing the paths first then the `bitmap`. It require some debugging to understand what is going on.

Comment: i have tried switching the order...when touch and start drawing on screen it will not show the line as the finger moves, and when finger removed from screen it show the drawn line but shifted by the adjustment

Comment: @pearmak did you manage to solve this?